# How can I password-protect applications behind mod_proxy in Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, passwords, basic-authentication, mod-proxy

I have a number of web applications running in a Tomcat instance.

They are fronted by an Apache instance, using mod_proxy.

Each web application is a silo in and of itself, each with its own user credential store and user authentication and authorisation. I want to continue using that.

However, I would like to apply simple password protection at the Apache level - maybe just a single known username/password using Basic Auth - before the requests are forwarded on to the Tomcat instance. Is this possible? and how can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this within the `<Location>` directive

Example:

```
ProxyPass /mytomcatapp http://localhost:8080/app1

<Location /mytomcatapp>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Wrapper auth"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile "/path/to/users.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This will give you HTTP Basic Auth when hitting yoursite.com/mytomcatapp

Comment: Thanks. That proved to be very useful and accurate.

Comment: I created an Apache config file called, say, foo.conf that has the ProxyPass directive and the Location directive.

Comment: I created a new file called foo.htpasswd in the same place (so in foo.conf, /path/to/users.htpasswd points to foo.htpasswd), and used the generator at http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ to create the usernames and passwords

Comment: You can use `<Location />` to apply this to the entire vHost.